# How to keep changing the the reference name by loop which is pointing to the object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, while-loop

I have declared a constructor in javascript. And I want to call that with different objects. But I want to change the name of the references by using loop but not manually.

I am trying this below code but seems an error in function CalculateTimeForEachOrbit.

**Code:**

```
let i = 1, totalOrbits = 6;

function CalculateTimeForEachOrbit (time) {
    this.time = time;
 }

  while (i <= totalOrbits)   {
         let orbit = "orbit";
         orbit = orbit + i;    
         const orbit+"bikeTime"  = new CalculateTimeForEachOrbit(10);
         const orbit+"tuktukTime"  = new CalculateTimeForEachOrbit(20);
         const orbit+"carTime"  = new CalculateTimeForEachOrbit(30);
    }
```

I want to set the time for each 6 orbits for every vehicle via loop instead of writing the object 6 times.

**Final Output Expected:**

```
Orbit1BikeTime :{
time : 10
}


Orbit1TuktukTime :{
time : 20
}

Orbit1CarTime :{
time : 20
}

Orbit2BikeTime :{
time : 10
}


Orbit2TuktukTime :{
time : 20
}

Orbit2CarTime :{
time : 20
}
```

Like this till Orbit6.

Comment: Where do you want these 18 objects to be stored?

Comment: [Dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5117127/1048572) are a bad idea